# JS function divides number in the thousands, hundreds, tens, etc.

Tags: javascript, numbers

For example I have a number 36543:
And I want to return an array with numbers:
30000
6000
500
40
3

But I need it to work well on other numbers as 13 or 185487542.

I can not figure out how to do it in JS

Comment: `12345 % 10 == 5` is what you need to know

Answer (score 8):

One possible one line solution:

```
36543..toString().split('').map(function(e, i, a) {
    return e * Math.pow(10, a.length - i - 1);
});  // [30000, 6000, 500, 40, 3]
```

**N.B.:** Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map#Browser_compatibility) for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) method and use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map#Polyfill) if required.

Answer (score 0):

(number - number % Math.pow(10,n)) where n [1,2,3,4....]